# Karma can't load junits plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, junit, karma-runner

I'm trying to create a xml file that contains my karma test output. My configuration is as follows but I do not get an xml file + i get an error on some junits plugin. How do I install this?

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(config) {

  config.set({
    autoWatch : false,
    reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins : [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine'
    ],
      junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'test-results-karma.xml',
        suite: ''
    }
  });
};
```

Output in cmd

```
[10:50:55] Using gulpfile C:\projects\gulpfile.js
[10:50:55] Starting 'test'...
[10:50:56] Starting Karma server...
WARN [reporter]: Can not load "junit", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket fsowdSE-rhiP0UWvIvdZ wit
h id 70609702
PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Windows 8): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.002 secs / 0.004 secs)
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You have to add the plugin in your karma.conf.js.
So this will look like:

```
 plugins : [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-junit-reporter'
    ]
```

Comment: My previous plugins were added with `require`, so in my case it looked like `plugins: [      ...      require('karma-junit-reporter'),      .....    ],`

Answer (score 3):

Try: npm install karma-junit-reporter

```
{
  "name": "project-template",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.11.4",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-file-process": "^0.2.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.1.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
    "karma": "~0.12",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

Here's my package.json I'm also using the junit reporter in my karma.conf.js not sure what you're missing exactly though.

Comment: I have this module installed